# Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.ModelBuilderService'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio. And I have updated Android Studio. Receiving following error like bellow

[image]
[ERROR: Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.ModelBuilderService'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msMS1.png)

Anyone can help me out

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have an active internet connections 
that should fix it but if it still persist go to your project and delete the gradle folder and resync with internet it should work the magic ,if it still doesnt i dont know if you are including any lib if you are make sure it added well or not confliting